# Product of two compacts set is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, products

Let $X $ and $ Y$  be two compact space . We shall prove that $X\times Y$ is compact. Let ${O_i}$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$, where $i \in F$=index set. Then  $O_i=U_i \times V_i$ where $U_i \subset X $ $ V_i \subset Y$, clearly ${U_i}$  and  ${V_i}$ are respectively open covers of $X$ and $ Y$.  As X and Y are compact , there exist finite subsets $A$ and $B$ of $F$ such that ${U_i:i\in A}$ is finite subcover of $X$ and  ${V_i:i\in B}$ is finite subcover of  $Y$. Therefore  ${O_i:i\in A\cup B}$ is finite subcover of  ${O_i}$  that covers $X\times Y$ .Thus $X\times Y$  is compact.

Is there anything wrong with this proof.

Comment: Yes, there is at least one flaw.  The set $O_i$ may not be of the form $U_i\times V_i$.

Comment: And another remark: any product (finite or infinite) of topological spaces is compact under the product topology.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem.

Comment: If we take $O_i$ are basic open set ? Then

Comment: You can't.  You must show that the axiom of compactness holds for **any** open cover of $X\times Y$, not just those of the form $U_i\times V_i$.

Comment: You may prefer to use sequential compactness

Comment: @dbx: How would that help? He wants to show that compactness is preserved, not sequential compactness...

Comment: @dbx  There are compact, but not sequentially compact, spaces.  There are also sequentially compact, but not compact, spaces.  The two terms are equivalent for metric spaces, but not in general.

Comment: Thanks @Batominovski ,now I can make out the necessity of tube lemma,used to prove this theorem in munkres' Topology. In stead of using basic  open set,a collection open tube has been constructed using pre-assigned open cover and the collection of open tubes is used in the same manner ,I have tried to use the basic open set in my proof.

Comment: So you get U1,.. Uj covering X and V1,.. Vk covering Y.  In the product there are jk terms and you'd have to show that each U is matched to the correct V so UxV is in the cover.

Comment: Maybe the next theorem can help you: Alexander Subbase Theorem. Let $X$ be a topological space with a subbasis $B$. If every cover by elements from $B$ has a finite subcover, then the space is compact. Recall that a subbasis of the product topology is the product of open sets of every factor.

Comment: @Batominovski Considering basic covers *is* enough.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, but the OP has to show why that is enough.  It is an easy step, but I consider it nontrivial enough.  If you simply claimed that in an exam with no proof, I am certain that most graders would deduct some points out of your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed enough to consider basic open covers as you did (despite some comments to the contrary): if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ then $X$ is compact iff every cover by elements from $\mathcal{B}$ has a finite subcover:

To see the sufficiency, let $\{O_i: i \in I\}$ be any open cover of $X$.
Then, for each $x$, $x \in O_{i(x)}$ for some $i(x) \in I$, and then there is a basic element $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq O_{i(x)}$.
Then $\{B_x: x \in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$ by members of $\mathcal{B}$, so by assumption this has a finite subcover $\{B_{x_1},\ldots, B_{x_n}\}$.

But then $\{O_{i(x_1)}, \ldots , O_{i(x_n}\}$ is a finite subcover of our original cover (as it is an enlargement of the subcover of base elements). So $X$ is compact.

But taking individual subcovers in the coordinates does not necesarily work, suppose that we were ding $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and we have $U=[0,\frac{3}{4}) \times U_2$ and $V=(\frac{1}{4},1] \times V_2$ in our basis covers we could pick 
the first components as the finite subcover in the first coordinate, but there is no guarantee that $U$ and $V$ then cover $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, because we pick the subcovers in the coordinates independently. This cannot easily be fixed, and you need a stronger idea. The tube lemma is one way to go. Another the Alexander subase theorem, which proves the same fact for subbases as we did for bases above, and is my preferred way (it also gives arbitary products in one fell swoop). Using [Alexander's subbase lemma](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1747),see [Wikipedia as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase):

Just note that $$\mathcal{S} = \{\pi_Y^{-1}[V] = X \times V: V \text{ open in } Y\}$ \cup \{\pi_X^{-1}[U] = U \times Y: U \text{ open in } X\}$$ together forms a subbase for $X \times Y$ (their finite intersections are just the standard basic elements $U \times V$, $U,V$ open). Now suppose we have a cover of $X \times Y$ by 
the sets $\mathcal{O}=\{\pi_X^{-1}[U_i], \pi_Y^{-1}[V_j], i \in I, j \in J\}$ from $\mathcal{S}$. Suppose the $\{U_i, i \in I\}$ do not form a cover of $X$, so some $x_0 \in X$ does not lie in any $U_i$ and also that $\{V_j : j \in J\}$ is not a cover of $Y$, so some $y_0$ is not covered them. Then clearly $(x_0, y_0)$ is not covered by  $\mathcal{O}$ at all, and this cannot be. So one of these families *is* a cover for $X$ resp. $Y$ and then we apply the compactness to get a finite subcover in that factor and the corresponding inverse images are then the required subcoevr for $\mathcal{O}$. QED.

Note that using the subbase removes the dependency on the other coordinates when choosing a subcover in a coordinate. This proof also works for any product (in he product topolgoy) where a similar natural subbase exists.